# What makes WSGI is synchronous in nature?

Tags: python, asynchronous, wsgi, synchronous

(Correct me if I made a mistake)

WSGI is a [standard interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Server_Gateway_Interface) for python based web application. But it's
said that WSGI is synchronous in nature. So, even something like `Tornado`
will handle WSGI app [synchonously](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/wsgi.html#tornado.wsgi.WSGIContainer). It means, the wsgi standard makes
python web app synchronous.

I don't have a good understanding on how asynchronous program works internally.
What I know is, async program doesn't wait `I/O` task until it's done to do
other tasks which doesn't involve `I/O` task.

If this is correct, a very basic python web server which handle wsgi app will
be something like this:

```
import socket


class Server(object):

    def __init__(self, host, port, app):
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.socket.bind((host, port))
        self.socket.listen(5)
        self.app = app

    def serve(self):
        while True:
            client, addr = self.socket.accept()
            request = client.recv()
            response_body = self.handle_app(request)
            client.sendall(response_body)
            client.close()

    def handle_app(self, request):
        # processing request stuff
        environ = self.environ_logic()  # some logics
        start_response = self.start_response_logic()  # some logics
        return self.app(environ, start_response)
```

So, what makes WSGI is synchronous in nature? With that example, which part
make it not `async`? And, is it possible to create a web server (in python)
that capable handling wsgi app asynchronously?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The interface between the webserver and the Python process it calls is synchronous -- as in the WSGI calling process is blocking, waiting for a response from the backend before it proceeds. Whatever happens within your Python code can be synchronous, asynchronous, or do whatever -- but the webserver's worker thread will block until it gets a response.

```
Webserver thread                      YourCode 
    |                                    |
    |       --callout to WSGI code-->    |
    |                                    |
    |                              [Do stuff ...]
[blocking]                         [     ...    ]
    |                              [Do stuff ...]
    |                                    |
    |                                  Done!
    |   <--Your response to the server-- |
 Proceed!
```

This does not mean this is the *only* thread in the webserver, of course.